# PHP sum function?

Tags: php, function, sum

i want to sum values of my array?
If have any php function that sum values of variable that existing multiple(more than one value)

Check this out this is my full example. I fetch check_in and check_out value from mysql then i calculate the difference in hours, minutes and seconds...After that how can i add all values of hours, minutes and seconds....? like this

I need this output like 
    hours = 3
    minutes = 36
    seconds = 55

```
for($i=0;$i<count($display_time); $i++)
        {
        $timeStart = $display_time[$i]["check_in"];
        $timeEnd =  $display_time[$i]["check_out"];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value ++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $display_time[$i]["date"];?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $display_time[$i]["check_in"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $display_time[$i]["check_out"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php



         $to_time = strtotime($timeStart);
        $from_time = strtotime($timeEnd);
        echo $time_in_hour = round(abs($from_time - $to_time) / (60 * 60)). " hour ";



        echo $time_in_minute = round(abs(($from_time - $to_time) / 60)%60). " minute ";
        echo $time_in_second = round(abs(($from_time - $to_time) / 60*60)%60). " secs ";




         $total_time = array($time_in_hour, $time_in_minute, $time_in_second);


            print_r($total_time);
                Array
                (
                    [0] => 0 hour 
                    [1] => 2 minute 
                    [2] => 25 secs 
                )

                Array
                (
                    [0] => 0 hour 
                    [1] => 3 minute 
                    [2] => 32 secs 
                )

                Array
                (
                    [0] => 0 hour 
                    [1] => 2 minute 
                    [2] => 51 secs 
                )
```

Comment: This is not clear. The `$total_time` assigned in your first line is a one-dimensional array. How do you get to the data as shown in the `print_r()`?

Comment: A foreach loop, sum in seconds, reformat that total in seconds at the end of the loop to suit your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand, but do you want to sum all the values of one array? Are the `$time_in_hour $time_in_minute $time_in_second` arrays with only hours, minutes or seconds values? In that case you may use:

```
// Count all values of all arrays in your array
foreach($mySubArray as $total_time){
    echo array_sum($mySubArray);
}
```

(Thanks to [halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) for [his suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428285/php-sum-function#comment34106151_22428422))

Comment: You've defined a new function when you could use the native function `array_sum`. To call a function, don't prefix it with a dollar symbol. Lastly, I'm not sure why the last loop is there - this will print out the sum of the array `count($mySubArray)` times.